# How to sum number in forEach

Tags: java

If I want to count v for sum in last line of code, What should I do. Sorry for bad english.

This is example output that I want.

Input word : เหม็น

__label__ความสะอาด, 2

__label__สัตว์, 1

__label__เผาในที่โล่ง, 1

Sum : 4

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Input word : ");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\input2.txt"));
    Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = ob.next();
    String str1 = "";
    Hashtable<String, Integer> db = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    while ((str1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
       
        String[] line = str1.split(" ");
        String label = line[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < line.length; i++) {
            if (line[i].equals(input)) {
                if (db.containsKey(label)) {  
                    int v = db.get(label);
                    v = v + 1;
                    db.put(label, v);
                } else {
                    db.put(label, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    db.forEach( (k, v) -> System.out.println( k + ", " + v) );
    System.out.print("Sum : ");  
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Unless your code causes a stackoverflow, you really should remove this tag!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum all the values of the `map`, you can use

```
int sum = db.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
```